# Merge contiguous "," into a single "," and remove leading and trailing "," in one RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string

```
",,,a,,,,,b,,c,,,,d,,,,"
```

I want to convert this into

```
"a,b,c,d"
```

in 1 `RegExp` operation.

I can do it in 2 `RegExp` operations like

```
var str = ",,,a,,,b,,,,c,,,,,,,,d,,,,,,";
str = str.replace(/,+,/g,",").replace(/^,*|,*$/g, '');
```

is it possible to do this in 1 `RegExp` operation ?

Comment: _"I want to convert this into "a,b,c,d" in 1 search 
I can do it in 2 searches"_ Can you describe precisely what "search" and "searches" is intended to mean at Question?

Comment: search basically means the number of RegExp operations required to convert the given string

Comment: _"search basically means the number of RegExp operations required to convert the given string"_ Have you considered including that description at Question, for clarity? This means that Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41493946/ meets requirement of original Question, yes?

Comment: yes it does, I'll update the description

Comment: To be clear, am not asking for own Answer to be accepted, or even voted upon. Accept the Answer which bests meets requirement. Just pointing out that text of original Question was not clear as to what "search" and "searches" were intended to mean as to requirement.

Comment: Another idea would be to target `,` not bordering to a word by use of `\B` (*non [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)*) [`^,+|,+\B`](https://regex101.com/r/kGIkU3/1) would also replace if `,` followed by such as `.` which might not be desired.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, which are at start or are followed by a comma or at the and and replace it with an empty string.

> `/^,*|,(?=,|$)/g`
>
> - **1st Alternative** `^,*`
>
>   `^` asserts position at start of the string
>
>   - `,*` matches the character `,` literally (case sensitive)
>
>     `*` **Quantifier** — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> - **2nd Alternative** `,+(?=,|$)`
>
>   - `,+` matches the character `,` literally (case sensitive)
>
>     `+` **Quantifier** — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>   - **Positive Lookahead** `(?=,|$)`
>
>     Assert that the Regex below matches
>
>     - **1st Alternative** `,`
>
>       `,` matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
>     - **2nd Alternative** `$`
>
>       `$` asserts position at the end of the string
> - **Global pattern flags**
>
>   `g modifier`: **g**lobal. All matches (don't return after first match)

```js
var string =  ",,,a,,,,,b,,c,,,,d,,,,";

console.log(string.replace(/^,*|,+(?=,|$)/g, ''));
```

Comment: Can you break down the pattern an explain how it works?

Comment: @OriDrori, just amoment, plz

Comment: @OriDrori You could look at the explanation at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Tpav18/1)

Comment: To make this more efficient with the number of replace operations you could use [`^,*|,+(?=,|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Tpav18/2)

Comment: @4castle - thanks. Nice feature on Regex101, that I haven't noticed.

Comment: I'd optimize it as `/^,+|,+(?![^,])/g`

Answer (score 4):

The approach below returns expected result using two processes. `.match()` and template literal, which casts the encapsulated `javascript` expression to string when assigned to a variable.

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[^,]+/` to negate matching comma character `,`, match one or more characters other than `,`, including `+` in `RegExp` following character class where `,` is negated to match `"abc"` as suggested by @4castle; template literal to cast resulting array to string.

```js
var str = ",,,a,,,b,,,,c,,,,,,,,d,,,efg,,,";

str = `${str.match(/[^,]+/g)}`;

console.log(str);
```

Comment: This has two operations, OP requested 1 operation.

Comment: @wdosanjos "join" isn't a search operation

Comment: @wdosanjos Was not certain what "search operation" meant.

Comment: @4castle Was not certain what "search operation" meant. Is requirement to only use a single function or method?

Comment: I think you meant to use `[^,]+` because currently it does unexpected things with `,,,abc,,,`

Comment: @4castle Not sure what you mean?

Comment: ",,,abc,,," should become "abc" but your code  is giving "a,b,c"

Comment: You just hid `join`, but it's still used under the hood. It's not a search operation anyways.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, you are correct. That was part that did not get when reading Question. What is a "search"? Is that portion of Question clear now? Without reading comments?

Comment: maybe `\`${str.match(/\w/g)}\`` is even better solution if you use toString

Comment: @maioman Probably several ways to achieve expected result. Did not gather that requirement was to use only one function. As Question now stands, it that clear? That is, what is "search"?

Comment: @maioman Note, _"",,,abc,,,""_ was also not included at original Question as a possible part of string, which `\w` would not match without `+`; as did not original `RegExp` at Answer which omitted `+` following character class negation.

Comment: @wdosanjos _"This has two operations, OP requested 1 operation."_ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493797/merge-contiguous-into-a-single-and-remove-leading-and-trailing-in-on/41493946?noredirect=1#comment70195837_41493797